# How to simplify code in ifelse statment in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Seems trivial but to clean up my code I would like to know if there is a way to consolidate my == arguments in a ifelse function

For Example:

```
vector = c(1,3,5,8,5,2,3,4,5,6,5,0,7,8,9)
new_vector <- ifelse(((vector==1)|(vector==3)|(vector==5)),"A","B")
```

Is there a way to combine the 1,3, and 5 into one argument? I tried

```
vector==c(1,3,5)
```

But this does not give me the correct output.

Comment: (You can still accept the answer once the interface allows you, but the dupe link is preferred. Thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `%in%` operator.

```
vector %in% c(1,3,5)
```

In your case,

new_vector <- ifelse(vector %in% c(1,3,5), "A", "B")

Comment: Wow that was quick, thanks so much. I'll accept the answer once it lets me.